# displaying pictures side by side in java

Tags: java, swing, javax.imageio

is it possible to display two pictures, next to each other with BufferedImage and Graphics2D ? or should I do it with other method ?

In my code below, I was able to display two images, but the picture 1 overlaps to the picture 2.

```
package zdjecie;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ObrazPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private BufferedImage image2;

    public ObrazPanel() {
        super();

    File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\KostrzewskiT\\eclipse-workspace\\zdjecie\\src\\zdjecie\\java.jpg");
    File imageFile2 = new File("C:\\Users\\KostrzewskiT\\eclipse-workspace\\zdjecie\\src\\zdjecie\\java2.jpg"); 

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            image2 = ImageIO.read(imageFile2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Blad odczytu obrazka");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        setPreferredSize(dimension);
        Dimension dimension2 = new Dimension(image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight());
        setPreferredSize(dimension2);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.drawImage(image2, 200, 200, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If they overlap, is it because you're not positioning them correctly?

Comment: so how to position them correctly Steve ?

Comment: And I think your `setPreferredSize(dimension);` code is wrong, since you're calling it on the JPanel.  Are you hoping this will change the size of the images?

Comment: Change the values in `g2d.drawImage(image2, 200, 200, this);` so they don't overlap.

Comment: `with BufferedImage and Graphics2D ` - why? Just create an ImagIcon from the BufferedImage and use the ImageIcon to create a JLabel. Then you just add the label to the panel and you can use whatever layout manager you want to show the images. The default FlowLabel of a JPanel with display the images side by side.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). (This is also demonstrated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54407143/418556) below.)

Answer (score 4):

You call `setPreferredSize` twice, which results in the first call doing basically nothing. That means you always have a `preferredSize` equal to the dimensions of the second image. What you *should* do is to set the size to `new Dimension(image.getWidth() + image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight())` assuming both have the same height. If that is not the case set the `height` as the maximum of both images.

Secondly you need to offset the second image from the first image exactly by the width of the first image:

```
g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
g2d.drawImage(image2, image.getWidth(), 0, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic of the math was incorrect. See the `getPreferredSize()` method for the correct way to calculate the required width, and the changes to the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method to place them side-by-side.

An alternative (not examined in this answer) is to put each image into a `JLabel`, then add the labels to a panel with an appropriate layout.

This is the effect of the changes:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ObrazPanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private BufferedImage image2;

    public ObrazPanel() throws MalformedURLException {
        super();

        URL imageFile = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg");
        URL imageFile2 = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH5zB.jpg");

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            image2 = ImageIO.read(imageFile2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Blad odczytu obrazka");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        int w = image.getWidth() + image2.getWidth();
        int h1 = image.getHeight();
        int h2 = image2.getHeight();
        int h = h1>h2 ? h1 : h2;
        return new Dimension(w,h);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // always best to start with this.. 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.drawImage(image2, image.getWidth(), 0, this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                ObrazPanel o;
                try {
                    o = new ObrazPanel();
                    JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                    f.setContentPane(o);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                    f.setVisible(true);
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some errors in your code and I did not got what are you trying to do...

1] Over there you are actually not using the first setup

```
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    setPreferredSize(dimension); //not used
    Dimension dimension2 = new Dimension(image2.getWidth(), image2.getHeight());
    setPreferredSize(dimension2); //because overridden by this
```

It means, panel is having dimensions same as the `image2`, you should to set it as follows:

- height as max of the heights of both images
- width at least as summarize of widths of both pictures (if you want to paint them in same panel, as you are trying)

2] what is the `image` and `image2` datatypes? in the block above you have `File` but with different naming variables, `File` class ofcourse dont have width or height argument

I am assuming its [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) due usage in `Graphics.drawImage`, then:

You need to **setup preferred size** as I mentioned:

- height to max value of height from images
- width at least as summarize value of each widths

Dimensions things:

```
Dimension panelDim = new Dimension(image.getWidth() + image2.getWidth(),Math.max(image.getHeight(),image2.getHeight()));
setPreferredSize(panelDim)
```

Then you can **draw images in the original size**
*- due coordinates are having 0;0 in the left top corner and right bottom is this.getWidth(); this.getHeight()* 
- check eg. [this explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html) 
- you need to start paint in the left bottom corner and then move to correct position increase "X" as the width of first image

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        /* public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,
        int x,
        int y,
        Color bgcolor,
        ImageObserver observer)
        */
    //start to paint at [0;0]
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this); 
    //start to paint just on the right side of first image (offset equals to width of first picture)- next pixel on the same line, on the bottom of the screen 
    g2d.drawImage(image2,image2.getWidth()+1, 0, this);
}
```

I didn't had a chance to test it, but it should be like this. 
Important things are

- you need to have proper dimensions for fitting both images
- screen coordinates starts in the left top corner of the screens [0;0]

Comment: `image` and `image2` are `BufferedImage`s.

Comment: It should works as well, `BufferedImage` is a child of `Image` if I am correct

Answer (score 1):

I would join the images whenever something changes and draw them to another buffered image. Then I can just redraw the combined image whenever the panel needs to be redrawn.

[image: Application]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SideBySideImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5868633578732134172L;
    private BufferedImage left;
    private BufferedImage right;
    private BufferedImage join;

    public SideBySideImagePanel() {
        ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        BufferedImage left = null, right = null;

        try {
            left = ImageIO.read(loader.getResourceAsStream("resources/Android.png"));
            right = ImageIO.read(loader.getResourceAsStream("resources/Java.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.setLeft(left);
        this.setRight(right);
    }

    public BufferedImage getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeft(BufferedImage left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public BufferedImage getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRight(BufferedImage right) {
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();
        join = combineImages(left, right);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(join.getWidth(), join.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(join, 0, 0, null);
    }

    private BufferedImage combineImages(BufferedImage left, BufferedImage right) {
        int width = left.getWidth() + right.getWidth();
        int height = Math.max(left.getHeight(), right.getHeight());
        BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
        Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();

        g.drawImage(left, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(right, left.getWidth(), 0, null);

        return combined;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Joiner");
                SideBySideImagePanel panel = new SideBySideImagePanel();

                frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```